# How to Monitor Database Changes in EF6 with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have two applications accessing a MySQL Database using EF6. I use one to input new data, and the other to display that data. However, I need to be notified upon changes to the database. I was duplicating the database then grabbing a new copy each time and comparing differences, however this is extremely inefficient.

Is there a way to monitor changes with EF6?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, afaik theres no way to get notified by the database via entity framework about any changes.

Usually you have to implement some communication between your two applications. There are several possibilities for that, the two to first come into my mind are:

- use some additional table in the DB where the first applications makes some "notes" when it changes data. These "notes" may contain a timestamp, so the second application can quickly decide, if there's anythin "new" in the database (the "notes" may contain additional information about what exactly has been added/changed)
- You could also implement some direct communication between the two applications using WCF/sockets/IPC whatever. Depending on your scenario, this might be more performant (and changes might been detected quicker), but this is usually more difficult to implement.

Comment: Martin, what about the LastModified value of an Entity?